# Distinct packages with identical function and variable names

Tags: packages

Trying to simulate namespaces, I have created two packages with nearly identical function and variable names, essentially, something like this:

```
BeginPackage["fruit`"];
fruitMain::usage="something";
Begin["`private`"];
nutritionalValue[f_]:=Module[{},_];
calories[f_]:=Module[{},_];
End[];
fruitMain[]:=Module[{},_];
EndPackage[];
```

and then, preferably in the same notebook (but a different nb would be OK)

```
BeginPackage["dairy`"];
dairyMain::usage="something";
Begin["`private`"];
nutritionalValue[f_]:=Module[{},_];
calories[f_]:=Module[{},_];
End[];
dairyMain[]:=Module[{},_];
EndPackage[];
```

But mathematica does not like this at all, talks about shadowing and being shadowed, syntax coloring indicates undefined variables and functions, etc.
In fact, it just doesn't work.  What can I do about this?  I really only want the functionality of namespaces in C++.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any error messages. Please post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: A side comment: *all* definitions should go into the private section, including `dairyMain`, otherwise you'll end up littering the package context with unwanted symbols.  If that Module had an `x` variable in it, it would be created in the dairy context.  Simply *mention* the symbols to be exported between BeginPackage and Begin.  Those not mentioned won't be exported

Comment: The code that produced the errors is much too bulky to post here, and that which I provided was just a contrived example to show the structure.  However, I have since come to believe that the problems I was experiencing were due to "stale" definitions created by the editing process, which was proceeding in two separate notebooks.  The upshot: my complaint was probably unfounded, and I apologize for burdening you with it, and at the same time thank you, C.E, for your assistance.  I consider the case closed, but being a newbie, don't know whether or how I can do this.

Comment: Well, I found out what the "real" problem was (duh): I was including an extra apostrophe in:

Begin["`private`"]

Of course, it should have been:
Begin["private`"]

Something to watch for.

Comment: ...continued...

Something to watch for.  It even seems to be confusing this editor.
I don't think it's going to display correctly.

So, to make a short story long,
I had a spurious back-single-quote in front of private in the Begin statement.

Answer (score 1):

You will get only warning messages (the shadowing message is only a warning, not an error) if there are symbols in the context `fruit` and `dairy` that overlap; putting them into any subcontext (e.g. `private`) will prevent shadowing. For example, defining a usage message for `calories` in the nonprivate part of the package will lead to warnings. Even then you can reference to the different symbols with `` fruit`calories `` and `` dairy`calories ``. Shadowing means that there might be ambiguities if you call `calories`: You know, it is like a box of chocolates...

Since you put `calories` into the `private` context, their full references are `` fruit`private`calories `` and `` dairy`private`calories ``.

Comment: I thank you as well, Hans, for your time and assistance.